# How can I see the records for a particular id on a master-detail CRUD?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have created a master-details CRUD. My view looks like this:

```
@model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel
<dt class="col-sm-2">
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ListaOtf)
</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-10">
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ListaOtf)
</dd>
(...)
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarBody.BarTelegramaFk.NrTg)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarBody.BarTelegramaFk.Continut1Tg)
            </th>
(...)
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.taBarBody)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BarTelegramaFk.NrTg)
        </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BarTelegramaFk.Continut1Tg)
            </td>
(...)
```

So, in the Details.cshtml for a particular ID I can see all the records of TaBarBody. There is a relationship one-to-many between TaBarHeader and TaBarBody.

**Controller**:

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            HeaderTelegramaViewModel headerTelegramaViewModel = new HeaderTelegramaViewModel();
            headerTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader = _unitofwork.BarHeader.DetailsBarH(id);
            headerTelegramaViewModel.taBarBody = _unitofwork.BarBody.GetAllBarB();
            return View(headerTelegramaViewModel);
        }
```

This is DetailsBarB() and DetailsBarH():

```
        public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> GetAllBarB()
        {
            return _db.TaBarBodies
                .Include(t => t.AnulatFk)
                .Include(t => t.ImpactFk)
                .Include(t => t.BarHeaderFk)
                .Include(t => t.BarTelegramaFk);
        }

        public TaBarHeader DetailsBarH(int? id)
        {
            return _db.TaBarHeaders
                .Include(t => t.CategoriaFk)
                .Include(t => t.CauzaFk)
(...)
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        }
```

All the data is displayed in the Details View but I don't know how to get all my records from TaBarBody to the Details View for a particular Id.

Everything works well, but I get all the records from TaBarBody. I need to display in the view only those TaBarBody that are having the Foreign key = Primary Id from TaBarHeader.
A TaBarHeader can have many TaBarBody.

Any ideas?

**Update**: Here are the requested models and viewmodels:

```
    public partial class TaBarHeader
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string ListaOtf { get; set; }
        public string NomCategoriaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomCategoriaId")]
        public TaNomCategoria CategoriaFk { get; set; }
        public string NomCauzaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomCauzaId")]
        public TaNomCauza CauzaFk { get; set; }
        public List<TaBarBody> TaBarBodies { get; set; }
}

    public partial class TaBarBody
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string NomImpactId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomImpactId")]
        public TaNomImpact ImpactFk { get; set; }
        public string NomAnulatId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomAnulatId")]
        public TaNomAnulat AnulatFk { get; set; }
        public int BarTelegramaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BarTelegramaId")]
        public TaBarTelegrama BarTelegramaFk { get; set; }
        public int BarHeaderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BarHeaderId")]
        public TaBarHeader BarHeaderFk { get; set; }
}

public class HeaderTelegramaViewModel
{
    public TaBarHeader TaBarHeader { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> taBarHeader { get; set; }
    public TaBarBody TaBarBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> taBarBody { get; set; }
}

public class BodyTelegramaViewModel
{
    public TaBarBody TaBarBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> taBarBody { get; set; }
    public TaBarTelegrama TaBarTelegrama { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarTelegrama> taBarTelegrama { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Start from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Can you add the models `TaBarBody` and `TaBarHeader`?

Comment: Yes, @SWilko . I have added them to the original post.

Comment: In the controller I'm loading a header and then all the bodies. I need to load the bodies for a header. But I have tried many queries and I can't find the correct one.

Comment: I might be missing something here but in `DetailsBarH` cant you just do this `_db.TaBarHeaders.Include(x => x.TaBarBodies).ThenInclude(x => x.BarTelegramaFk)`